# Using Provided Artifact As Maven Plugin Dependency

Tags: maven, plugins, dependencies, version, wildfly

This seems like it should be a simple question, but I can't seem to find any information about it. When a maven plugin has a required dependency, is it possible to tell it to use an artifact defined elsewhere in the  section of the pom?

As an example, I'm trying to add the 'maven-processor-plugin' to my build. That plugin has a dependency on 'hibernate-jpamodelgen'. I'm working with wildfly, so I already have that jar as a dependency of the project. I want to ensure I am using the same version for both. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Some code snippets:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-ejb3</artifactId>     
            <version>${version.server.bom}</version>           
            <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <processor>-proc:none</processor>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>4.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java/jpametamodel</outputDirectory>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <!-- How do I handle this without hard coding the version? -->
                    <!-- <version>???</version> -->
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a property like `<hibernate-jpamodelgen.version>` in the `<properties>` section of the POM.

Then use that property for the version like `${hibernate-jpamodelgen.version}`.

Comment: I thought of that. The problem is, the version number for hibernate-jpamodelgen is defined in the wildfly pom. I could see if I can use whatever property they define, but I still run the risk of my pom breaking if they ever change the name of that property.